# Why string str = new string("abc") doesn't pass compiler?

Tags: c#, string

Given `public String(char*)` why we cannot use the following statement?

```
string str = new string("aaa");
```

Error   1

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'string.String(char*)' has some
>   invalid
>   arguments C:\temp\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs  19  26  ConsoleApplication2

Error   2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'string' to
>   'char*'   C:\temp\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs  19  37  ConsoleApplication2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use:

```
 string str = "aaa";
```

You do not need to `new` a string.

"aaa" is a string.  It is not a `char *`.
`char *` is used with `unsafe` code.

Answer (score 6):

Because this isn't meant to be used in safe code...

> In C#, this constructor is defined only in the context of unsafe code.

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y4za026.aspx

If you need to construct a string you could just use the literal decleration..

```
string str = "aaa";
```

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to call a constructor with a string as a parameter.

The compiler is telling you there is no string constructor with a single string as a param.

Comment: so in C# "aaa" doesn't mean a type of char*?

Comment: @g0987 nope it is always a System.String which is UTF-16 encoded string

Answer (score 4):

The type `char*` is for an unsafe pointer -- to an object not part of the .Net managed framework.  When you place the literal string `"aaa"` in your code, that's a managed object.  `string` is not `char*` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

have look to this may resolve your doubt [C# New String Constructor](http://www.dotnetperls.com/new-string-constructor)

```
unsafe public String(char*);
       public String(char[]);
unsafe public String(sbyte*);
       public String(char, int);
unsafe public String(char*, int, int);
       public String(char[], int, int);
unsafe public String(sbyte*, int, int);
unsafe public String(sbyte*, int, int, Encoding);
```

Comment: I did check these info before I posted my question. After reading the message from this thread, I got the basic idea. -- thx

Comment: @q0987 - as you see the doc you need to pass the char array you cannot pass the string value...i am not getting well y you passed the string if you already have information about it....